# How can I make entityQuery('commerce_order') return completed orders?

Tags: entities, commerce

Under Drupal Commerce 8.x-2.13 I find that the query

```
Drupal::entityQuery('commerce_order')
```

with no conditions attached returns ONLY incomplete orders (when called in the context of an API endpoint) - and if I apply any parameters exclusive of incomplete orders such as

```
$query->condition('state', 'completed');
```

it returns nothing. How can entityQuery be made to retrieve data on completed orders?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is apparently to add `$query->accessCheck(FALSE);`.